# Logging in spring integration java DSL

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I want to print message log in the console and write in a log file. I am trying with ***logging-channel-adapter***, ***LoggingHandler***
please give me sample code. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use one of the `.log()` operators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-log).

> For convenience, to log the message journey through the Spring Integration flow (), a log() operator is presented. Internally, it is represented by the WireTap ChannelInterceptor with a LoggingHandler as its subscriber. It is responsible for logging the incoming message into the next endpoint or the current channel. The following example shows how to use LoggingHandler:

```
.filter(...)
.log(LoggingHandler.Level.ERROR, "test.category", m -> m.getHeaders().getId())
.route(...)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working. One thing is remaining that is I want to write this log into a file. Can you please help.

Comment: You should consult your logging subsystem documentation (log4j, logback etc). Normally you would configure a file appender and then configure the log category (`test.category` in the above example) to use the file appender.